# Merge objects properties in new objects and push in array without jquery and lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have array of objects with has same properties. How can I merge objects with same `period` property to new array of objects. I saw the examples in stackoverflow, but they are mostly using external libraries like JQuery or lodash. Can i make this in vanilla.js?

**[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BiFNUHTraDG2fxSO4UJd)** is Plunkr with the markup of code and expected value. Thank you for helping

Comment: this can be achieved with JavaScript only with the use of 2 nested for loops.

Comment: Thank's for answers for everyoune!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group it with the day and use an object as reference to the hash table. Another object is used for the access of day/nicht property.

```js
var array = [{ period: '01.07.2016', count: 11, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.07.2016', count: 22, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 33, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 44, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 55, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 66, scale: 'n' }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var day = a.period.slice(3, 5);
    if (!this[day]) {
        this[day] = { date: day, day: 0, night: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[day]);
    }
    this[day][{ d: 'day', n: 'night' }[a.scale]] += a.count;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could use a closure over the hash table as well, without using `thisArg`.

```js
var array = [{ period: '01.07.2016', count: 11, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.07.2016', count: 22, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 33, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 44, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 55, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 66, scale: 'n' }],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (hash) {
    return function (a) {
        var day = a.period.slice(3, 5);
        if (!hash[day]) {
            hash[day] = { date: day, day: 0, night: 0 };
            grouped.push(hash[day]);
        }
        hash[day][{ d: 'day', n: 'night' }[a.scale]] += a.count;
    };
}(Object.create(null)));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Clean version without abusing `thisArg` and an IFFE

```js
var array = [{ period: '01.07.2016', count: 11, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.07.2016', count: 22, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 33, scale: 'n' }, { period: '01.08.2016', count: 44, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 55, scale: 'd' }, { period: '01.09.2016', count: 66, scale: 'n' }],
    grouped = function () {
        var result = [],
            hash = Object.create(null);

        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var day = a.period.slice(3, 5);
            if (!hash[day]) {
                hash[day] = { date: day, day: 0, night: 0 };
                result.push(hash[day]);
            }
            hash[day][{ d: 'day', n: 'night' }[a.scale]] += a.count;
        });
        return result;
    }();

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'vent seen any example of `thisArg` in MDN. Glad to know this thing.

Comment: @shyammakwana.me ... for good reason ... Opinion:  preserving context by providing it as target object via `forEach`'s 2nd argument unfortunately is not seen that often. But bending it too much as in both upvoted answers - in both cases (mis)using the context/target as kind of helper object in order to nail state onto it - is by no means sophisticated but just harder to read. There is already `reduce` for iterating and in the same time preserving/collecting/working with additional state.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, but reduce for just keeping a state is a misuse of reduce as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz ... I do not really agree for the argument's api of `reduce` does explicitly encourage the use of an accumulator/collector. Such a collector not necessarily needs to be a primitive value or a list, it as well can be a plain object. ...

Comment: @NinaScholz ... The `thisArg` as in all other `Array` iterating methods mainly is for preserving/providing original `this` context which of cause can be bend in its usage as been seen from e.g. your example. But nevertheless that's in my opinion something that a programmer does not expect at first place. I once was on this *clever* path too, but for long term team and maintaining compatibility I was better of with changing this habit.

Comment: yes, i agree with `thisArg`, but for reduce with an object, it does not follow the style, that the result of reduce should be changing, but with the same object, or array (), the reference does not really change. btw, reduce does not have a `thisArg`.

Comment: @NinaScholz - The result of `reduce`, thus the data-type of an accumulator and/or the provided `initialValue`, can be anything from number (processing/summarizing list of numbers) and string (e.g. concatenating list of strings) to array and object (both for lists of more complex data-structures). And of course the accumulator always gets processed/changed within every iteration step that matches the condition of the `callback` function. ... *"btw, reduce does not have a thisArg"* ... I never said that, and it does not need to, since there is this `initialValue` that could carry `thisArg` too.

Comment: but why should i use reduce and use the accumulator as `thisArg`. then i could use `forEach` directly.

Comment: @NinaScholz ... Please Nina, do you really read? I never advocated *"use reduce and use the accumulator as `thisArg`"*. I was pointing to not misusing `thisArg` in array iterator methods as You did with your example. But I also said, that in those rare cases, where one really was  in need of using `reduce` and depending on `this` in the very same time, one easily can solve this, by making `this` part of an accumulator object that gets provided as `initialValue` (which might be the reason for `thisArgs` not being part of the arguments signature of `reduce`). Everything else belongs to the chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()` loop and add to new array.

```js
var a = [{"period":"01.07.2016","count":11,"scale":"d"},{"period":"01.07.2016","count":22,"scale":"n"},{"period":"01.08.2016","count":33,"scale":"n"},{"period":"01.08.2016","count":44,"scale":"d"},{"period":"01.09.2016","count":55,"scale":"d"},{"period":"01.09.2016","count":66,"scale":"n"}]

var result = []
a.forEach(function(e) {
  if (!this[e.period]) {
    this[e.period] = {
      date: e.period.split('.')[1],
      day: 0,
      night: 0
    }
    result.push(this[e.period])
  }
  if (e.scale == 'd') {
    this[e.period].day = (this[e.period].day || 0) + e.count
  } else if (e.scale == 'n') {
    this[e.period].night = (this[e.period].night || 0) + e.count
  }
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **forEach** to loop over the array and **some** to check if an object with same key is already present to merge the object.

P.S:  you expected output has an error for period: "01.08.2016". It has switched count of day and night.

```js
var a = [{
  'period': "01.07.2016",
  'count': 11,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': "01.07.2016",
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
}, {
  'period': "01.08.2016",
  'count': 33,
  'scale': 'n'
}, {
  'period': "01.08.2016",
  'count': 44,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': "01.09.2016",
  'count': 55,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': "01.09.2016",
  'count': 66,
  'scale': 'n'
}]


function createMatrix(list) {
  var arr = [];
  list.forEach((item) => {
    var key = item["period"];
    var result = arr.some(function(currentValue, index, arr) {
      if (arr[index].date == key.split(".")[1]) {
        var dayNight = (item.scale == "d" ? "day" : "night");
        arr[index][dayNight] = item.count;
        return true;
      }
    });

    if (result === false) {
      var dayNight = (item.scale == "d" ? "day" : "night");
      var obj = {};
      obj[dayNight] = item.count;
      obj["date"] = key.split(".")[1];
      arr.push(obj);
    }

  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(createMatrix(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

One also firstly could sort the raw data list by 'd'ay `scale` and then within one `reduce` get the targeted/desired list collected ... like .e.g. ...

```js
var rawData = [{
  'period': '01.07.2016',
  'count': 11,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': '01.07.2016',
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
}, {
  'period': '01.08.2016',
  'count': 33,
  'scale': 'n'
}, {
  'period': '01.08.2016',
  'count': 44,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': '01.09.2016',
  'count': 55,
  'scale': 'd'
}, {
  'period': '01.09.2016',
  'count': 66,
  'scale': 'n'
}];


// expecting
/*
  result = [{
    date  : '07',
    day   : 11,
    night : 22
  }, {
    date  : '08',
    day   : 44,
    night : 33
  }, {
    date  : '09',
    day   : 55,
    night : 66
  }]
*/


function sortByDay(a, b) {
  return ((a.scale < b.scale) ? -1 : ((a.scale > b.scale) ? 1 : 0));
}

function collectSortedDayAndNightTotals(collector, item/*, idx, list*/) {
  var
    dateRegistry    = collector.dateRegistry,
    dateKey         = item.period,
    registeredItem  = dateRegistry[dateKey];

  if (registeredItem == null) {
    dateRegistry[dateKey] = item;
  } else {
    collector.totalList.push({
      date  : dateKey.split('.')[1],
      day   : registeredItem.count,
      night : item.count
    });
  }
  return collector;
}


var result = rawData.sort(sortByDay).reduce(collectSortedDayAndNightTotals, {

  dateRegistry: {},
  totalList   : []

}).totalList;


console.log('result : ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used with reduce

```
var arr = [{
  'period': '01.07.2016',
  'count': 11,
  'scale': 'd'
},
{
  'period': '01.07.2016',
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
},
{
  'period': '01.07.2016',
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
},
{
  'period': '01.08.2016',
  'count': 11,
  'scale': 'd'
},
{
  'period': '01.08.2016',
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
},
{
  'period': '01.08.2016',
  'count': 22,
  'scale': 'n'
},
];


function functionName(a) {
  var b = [];
  var c = 0;

  var d = a.reduce(function(first, second, i){
    if(first.period == second.period){
        b[c] = b[c] || [{
        day: '',
        night: '',
        date: '',
      }];
      if (first.scale == 'd') {
        b[c].day = b[c].day + first.count || first.count;
      }else {
        b[c].night = b[c].day + first.count || first.count
      }
      b[c].date = b[c].date  || first.period;
    }else {
      c= c + 1;
    }
    return second;
  });
  b[c] = b[c] || [{
    day: '',
    night: '',
    date: '',
  }];
  if (d.scale == 'd') {
    b[c].day = b[c].day + d.count || d.count;
  }else {
    b[c].night = b[c].day + d.count || d.count;
  }
  b[c].date = b[c].date  || d.period;
  return b;

}

console.log(functionName(arr));
```